# i want to replace snackbar with alert dialog , how in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

`Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Restart to update", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)`

i want change this to alert dialog, need help

Comment: Please do some research before posting question . There is no magic Stick to convert component one to another . You need to create one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#kotlin)

To implement an `AlertDialog` you need to use the `AlertDialog.Builder` class too setup the `AlertDialog`. Then you can use the `.create()` method to create the `AlertDialog`, and then finally `.show()` of `AlertDialog` class to show the dialog.

```
val alertDialog: AlertDialog? = activity?.let {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
    builder.apply {
        setMessage("This is the message")
        setTitle("This is the title")
        setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                    // User clicked OK button
                })
        setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                    // Use this to dismiss dialog
                    dialog.dismiss()
                })
    }
    // Set other dialog properties
    ...

    // Create the AlertDialog
    builder.create()
}

alertDialog.show()
```

You can use this to `dismiss` the dialog:

```
alertDialog.dismiss()
```